# python function with numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, anaconda

I'm using anaconda with python 2.7. How can I do a function with parameters recognized by the IDE as for example np.array? In order to use the method of the type?

```
import numpy as np

    def calculate_variance(weight,sigma):
       return weight.transpose * sigma * weight
```

How can I do when I write the "dot" after the word "weight" it complete me with the methods of the np.array type?

Comment: How did it not work? What were the errors? It's difficult to help with limited information. And if you're trying to define a function it's `def`, not `do`.

Comment: @aus_lacy I edited the question in order to do it more readable. Please tell me if is clear now.

Comment: Well assuming the `weight` that you are passing in is a `numpy` array then you need to do `return np.transpose(weight) * sigma * weight`.

Comment: @aus_lacy thanks! I'm going to try it

Comment: Let me know if it works for you and I will submit an answer for it.

Comment: And you should make your function definition like `def calculate_variance(weight, sigma):`. Exclude the space between `calculate` and `variance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is this assuming your `weight` is a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

    def calculate_variance(weight,sigma):
       return np.transpose(weight) * sigma * weight
```

Also, notice how I took out the space between `calculate` and `variance` within your function definition and added an underscore.